# .Offset when copy the data to ListBox - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to copy cells value to multiple columns listbox1 using the code below. The problem is that it only works if and only if Sheet3 is active, otherwise, I have nothing in Listbox1.

I tried `Range.cells(cell.offset...)` but it does not work either. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  With Me.ListBox1
.Clear
.ColumnCount = 6
.ColumnWidths = "20;60;260;80;50;50"
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet3.Name).Range(Cells(13, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7), Cells(txIndex.text, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7))
    If cell = "O" Or cell = "o" Then
        .AddItem cell
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = cell.Offset(0, 4)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = cell.Offset(0, 2)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = cell.Offset(0, 7)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = cell.Offset(0, 9)
    End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: Currently, I have a workaround by active the Sheet3, then move back to the sheet I am working (which is not sheet3)

Comment: @Alireza - if I run the code on sheet that is not sheet3, then the error is Run-Time error '1004', Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: On which line of the code?

Comment: 'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet3.Name).Range(Cells(13, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7), Cells(txIndex.text, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7))' - this is fine as long as I run my code on sheet3 - which is kind of strange to me

Comment: Try this:     Dim Sheet: Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet3.Name):
    For Each cell In sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(13, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7), sheet.Cells(txIndex.text, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this code.  The line

```
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet3.Name).Range(Cells(13, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7), Cells(txIndex.text, cbPartList.ListIndex + 7))
```

breaks down as follows

1. `Sheet3` in `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet3.Name)1 is the code name of a sheet in the workbook containing the VBa code that is executing.  It may or may not be valid for the`ActiveWorkbook`
2. `Cells(...)` refers to a cell in the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Collectively this will only work if the `Activeworkbook` is the book containing the code, and `Sheet3` is active

You should;

declare and Set a workbook variable

```
Dim wb as Workbook
```

set a refernce to a specific workbook.  This *may* be the active book

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

or a specific workbook

```
Set wb = Workbooks("Name of Workbook")
```

Then declare a worksheet variable, and set it to a specific worksheet

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = wb.WorkSheets("SheetName")
```

(If you specifically want to use `CodeName`s this will be a little different)

When you declare the loop, use

```
Dim Cell as Range

With ws
    For each Cell in .Range(.Cells(...), .Cells(...))
```

Note the `.`'s.  These refer to the `With` block object

Comment: thank very much, especially for pointing out what I did wrongly. :) it is much better then my workaround with switch between sheet3 and another sheet

Comment: May I add, whenever you are working with multiple sheets, try to always point the Sheet you're targeting and eventually use the `.Address` command to address Cells/Ranges